# How to convert .snk file to .pfx file

Tags: .net, assembly-signing

How does one convert a .snk file (for strong-name signing .NET assemblies) into a password protected .pfx file suitable for the same purpose?

Edit: to clarify, suppose I create a project in VS and in project properties, Signing, click 'New strong name key file', and elect not to protect the key file with a password:

[image: CreateStrongKeyVS]

Now imagine that a year later I change my mind and want to add a password - without trashing the assembly's identity by creating a new keypair. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a snk from pfx / cer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174229/how-to-create-a-snk-from-pfx-cer)

Comment: @Matt - not really: that describes how to go in the opposite direction (pfx -> snk) although there may be some clues there

Comment: I see. I have removed the close vote.

Answer (score 5):

You do not convert however you *can* sign an existing *snk* file using the *[Strong Name Tool (Sn.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)*. (There are a few steps involved if the *snk* is already been protected as you need to split the *strong-name* part from the certificate).

The *pfx* is a private certificate that is created for you in Visual Studio when you select the password protection option. The password you enter is used to protect this certificate.

Is this for development or for commercial release? I would not recommend signing the assemblies with private key for development.

From the [CLR Inside Out Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx):

> While password-protecting your key files is a much better solution
>   than storing them in the clear, it is still not ideal. You would still
>   have to distribute the PFX file to all of your developers, and they
>   would all have to know the password for the PFX file. Secrets that are
>   widely shared like this do not tend to stay secret for very long.
>   Ideally, you should not have to distribute the private key to build
>   and test your code during development.

Read CLR Inside Out (MSDN) Article on [Using Strong Name Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163583.aspx).

HTH,

Comment: Yes: password-protecting key files is much better than storing them in the clear. Therefore I want to convert my (non-password-protected) snk into a (password-protected) pfx without changing the public key and losing the assembly's identity. I don't have the multi-developer problem, so a password-protected pfx is ideal and less cumbersome than delay-signing.

Comment: I would argue the password-protecting is still *not* ideal. However ... I believe it is possible to do this using the Strong Name Tool (Sn.exe) - there are options to extract the public key (-p) and then recombine them. I have not needed to do such before so you will have to figure *exactly* how (what arguments etc) yourself.

Comment: sn.exe has options to extract the public key, but not the private key. The only option that seems to extract the private key is -i which copies it into the CSP - unfortunately it marks it as non-exportable

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. ... Possibly your only option will be to discard the *existing* snk file and sign with a **new** password-protected key.

Comment: [Actually you can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11461474/521757) extract the full SNK from a PFX, including private key.