# How to convert snk to pfx using PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, pfx, snk

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174229/how-to-create-a-snk-from-pfx-cer/39549924#39549924) gave a method for converting a pfx to snk using powershell (wrapped around the `System.Security.Cryptography` methods).

How would I do the reverse, convert a `.snk` file to `.pfx`? I can read the `.snk` file with `Get-Content`, and somehow use `ImportCspBlob` to get an `X509Certificate2` object, but I do not know:

1. How to instantiate `ImportCspBlob` to get that certificate object
2. How to export a `.pfx` from that object

For what it's worth, I tried to instantiate an `X509Certificate2` and then run `ImportCspBlob`, but the constructor failed:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2();
At line:1 char:83
+ ... ect System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2();
+                                                                        ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

EDIT:

@TheIncorrigible pointed out the constructor problem, which now is fixed. Main questions still remain.

I expected the empty constructor to work.

UPDATE:

I no longer have need for this question. Turns out it was *not* a public-private keypair in the `.snk` file, but rather some basic symmetric key material, password-encrypted. I will leave the question, though, in case the answer is useful to others.

Comment: I like your handle @TheIncorrigible. Yeah, PowerShell is not my strength, but adapt, I must. So... how?

Comment: Is `.snk` considered a X509 cert?

Comment: In a unique fashion, yes. Can include both private and public keys or just public key. Password encrypted (well, symmetric key generated from password, I am guessing PBKDF). It is identical to a CSP blob. But how would I actually run `ImportCspBlob`?

Comment: In the example, you would do the same thing they did with importing the pfx cert: `[byte[]] $snkBytes = Get-Content -Path $snkFilePath -Encoding Byte` and then create the `$cert` object in the same fashion.

Comment: I can pass the `$snkBytes` like they passed the `$pfxBytes`? I didn't think I could. The docs say that it should be used with a pfx file, which this is not.

Comment: [As long as it's a x.509 cert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148418(v=vs.110).aspx), I don't see that being an issue.

Comment: But it is a different format? Well, I can try.

Comment: And no. I get errors.

Comment: Are you specifying the CSP (`sn.exe -c`) when you create the keypair?

Comment: I am not creating the keypair, it is exported from an app. I am trying to reverse it, make it manageable.

Comment: I suggest you look at the code that is in this module PSPKI GitHub location: https://github.com/Crypt32/PSPKI you might be able to locate a good answer in his code.

Comment: @thomschumacher I saw some pem-pfx conversion utils, and PKI interactions, but not much on dealing with a local snk file. It shouldn't be this hard. :-(

Comment: OK, so I read through that post you linked to and have a better understanding of your problem.  Does your `.snk` contain only the public RSA key?

Comment: I am fairly certain it contains public and private, given that it is password-protected. All of this is just around managing keys for PowerBI, believe it or not. I can export the keys, now I need to inspect them.

Comment: I would be thrilled if I could just run the thing through `sn` or `openssl` and get straightforward info about it.