# How to sign F# class library in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, f#, code-signing, class-library

Ive been trying to sign a FSharp Class library in visual studio and i am not sure what went wrong. when i select create a new strong name key file, visual studio will force restart. the  below gif is a demo of me trying to sign the package.

[image]

i tried to create a snk file with in command line but i need to create a snk file with password protected given the D365 plugin require so. Any advice are appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Is this a .NET Core library or .NET Framework?

Comment: @BrianBerns this is visual studio 2019 and it is a .Net Framework library

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio these kind of issues can be caused by a bad behaving extension or perhaps a corrupted project file. Disable suspected extensions and try again.

Another fix is creating an snk file using the **Strong Name Utility** snk.exe and adding it to the project by hand. Remember, the signing tab of your project is just a handy UI for the underlying fsproj file.

Steps:

1. Open the developer command prompt.
2. Type `snk.exe -k mykey.snk`.
3. Open your `.fsproj` file and add the following lines:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>mykey.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

4. Compile your project and you're done.

An alternative for step 3 is adding an assembly attribute to your project:

```ml
[<assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("mykey.snk")>]
```

See also [How to: Create a public-private key pair - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-public-private-key-pair).

Comment: thanks for the advice. i am just wonder if do you know how to add password to the snk when create because i dont seem to find it in the documentation.

Comment: It is not possible to add a password using sn.exe. Instead you would need to create a _code-signing certificate_ (PFX) and _delay sign_ your assembly with that. This is typically done in a release build pipeline. ([Code signing](https://bettersolutions.com/csharp/projects/properties-signing.htm))

Comment: These contributions on StackOverflow may also be helpful: [How to create a snk from pfx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174229/how-to-create-a-snk-from-pfx-cer/11461474#11461474).